# Wireless Keyboard and Mouse

Tags: wireless-networking, keyboard, mouse, interference

I have a small business that we would like to run 30 pairs of wireless mice and keyboard in a 60x60 ft<sup>2</sup> room. Will there be any interference doing so? Will this cause any effect to any of the other users in the same room?

Comment: No interference to speak of, but if you buy batteries at the same time, you'll have howls of dispair when they run out at the same time too.

Comment: How will the machines be networked? Beware that 802.11 B and G (and some N) use the same 2.4GHz frequency band as Bluetooth, so you might have a lot of contention for airtime there unless you give the machines wired Ethernet connections, or make sure they use 5GHz only (802.11 A, some N) for their Wi-Fi network.

Answer (score 1):

There are two type of wireless technologies:

- 27MHz radio frequency and
- Bluetooth (which operates in 2.45GHz range)

Using Bluetooth technology will not cause any interference when using wireless mice and keyboards set.

**Note:** When using wireless routers be aware of the working frequency. Like Spiff mentioned, some wireless network devices might work at the same frequency.

However Bluetooth can suffer interference from microwave ovens and baby monitors. *Consider this when using Bluetooth keyboard and mice set*

The 27MHz keyboard and mice can work with baby monitors or microwave ovens nearby, but there are some restrictions when using them in a crowded place with lots of others keyboards and mice of the same type.

Older 27MHz keyboards are more susceptible to interference, but newer keyboards can work nearby using channels. Some of them (not all vendors) have four channels, two for the mice and two for the keyboard. You can adjust and test the channels used within the range (that can vary from 3 feet to 30 feet).

From [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-troubleshooting-wireless-keyboards-and-mice/5807296), the recomendation when using 27MHz keyboards:

> if you're in a groupsetting, but with
>   less than ten or eleven people, and
>   multiple people are using wireless
>   keyboards and mice, try them one at a
>   time to see if interference really is
>   the problem

This will not worth when you have 30 pairs of wireless mice and keyboard.

If you don't have microwave ovens nor baby monitor in your environment I would recommend to use Bluetooth keyboard/mouse set.

Other things you should be aware of when using wireless keyboard/mouse set:

- Battery life
- Range
- Security

See more about at [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/solutionbase-troubleshooting-wireless-keyboards-and-mice/5807296).